# boolean as if-else condition

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

Hi I am new to python and would like to confirm how a variable with Boolean values works in an if-else statement.

```
def fun(a, b, reverse):
    if reverse:
        print(b, a)
    else:
        print(a, b)
```

Here 'reverse' can be either True or False. So can I say it is by default that 'if reverse' is just 'if reverse is True'?

Because strictly speaking I do not see how 'if some boolean' actually fix the value of the boolean variable. (to 'if some boolean evaluates to True')

Any help is appreciated!

---

Edit:
Apologies I realise this code is straightforward. Please ignore the previous example. I will use this one which conveys my question accurately.

```
def is_even(i):
    return i%2 == 0
for i in range(20):
    if is_even(i):
        print(i, 'is even')
    else:
        print(i, 'is odd')
```

I would like to confirm this: here is_even() carries the argument i to the if-else clause. If is_even(i) evaluates to True then the code under if statement is carried out. If False then we jump to the code under else statement.

I wonder if it is by default that when we do not have 'if bool = true:' but just 'if bool', the if-code takes the 'bool = True' result; else-code takes the 'bool = False' result?

Sorry for the troubles as I just found that the previous example already has the boolean value confirmed in the argument; but in this case the boolean value is only known after for loop iteration through each i's.

Comment: did you try to run it ? Is this not working?

Comment: It isn’t clear what you’re asking, can you explain things further? I have seen some people write `if ... is True:`, are you referring to that?

Answer (score 2):

`if x:` considers `x` as a boolean. It's similar to (for the purposes of this discussion, identical to) casting `x` to a boolean (that is, `bool(x)`).

Non-boolean objects can parse as either `True` or `False` when we try to convert them this way - we call them Truthy or Falsey. For example:

- integers are falsey when they are 0, and truthy otherwise
- The empty string `''` is falsey, all other strings are truthy
- All collections (`list`, `dict`, `set`, etc.) are falsey when empty and truthy when non-empty
- `None` is falsey. Most non-`None` objects evaluate as truthy by default, unless other behavior has been set (as in the three cases above).

In your case, as @AshkayNevrekar answers, you can give `False` as a default value for the `reverse` argument in your function. This way, a caller can call `fun()` without specifying `reverse` and it'll not reverse anything; or, they can pass in *any truthy value* and it *will* reverse the arguments.

---

If you want to check, for whatever reason, whether your argument is *exactly* a boolean (and not just truthy or falsey), then you can do `if x is True:` or `if x is False:`; the values `True` and `False` are singletons, and the only possible values of a `bool`. This will prevent the condition from triggering if it's given, say, a truthy integer.

Comment: Hi I have realised that in the previous code the boolean variable is already determined in the argument. Sorry for the troubles but could you take a look at the new example I added?

Comment: @siegfried A boolean check (using any of the operators `==`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `is`) essentially resolves to either `True` or `False`. in this case, that `True` or `False` gets returned by the function, and that value gets used directly by the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to return values and assign back

```
def fun(a, b, reverse=False):
    if reverse:
        return b,a
    return a, b

a,b = fun(a,b,True)
```

Comment: Hi I have realised that in the previous code the boolean variable is already determined in the argument. Sorry for the troubles but could you take a look at the new example I added?